# Is it possible to take a reserved ip from VM and place it in Azure Load Balancer? :-)

Tags: load-balancing

I was thinking here in a solution that could help me achieve a scenario without  (much) service disruption.

I have today a VM that is not part of a virtual network, so in order to add a VNIC to it, I would have to delete the VM keeping the disk, and so on so on...

Since the VM has a reserved IP, could I take it off from the VM(this part is possible!) and place the reserve on the Load Balancer?

That way the LB would keep servicing my VM, I would create a side by side VM, with the proper configuration(VIrtual net, and stuff...), and be able to take use of internal communication between this VM, and a Backup VM, to copy data between them faster than over public ip.

Just a thought :) I would not think it possible, but it's worth the try...

Cheers

Nuno